# Selenium says invalid xpath for span

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

HTML :

```
<div class="accept"><a class="red_keep popup_action"><span>Click here to view terms</span></a></div>
```

Xpath which I have tried :

```
1. //span[text()='Click here to view terms']
2. normalize-space(//href[@class="red_keep popap_action"]/text()='Click here to view terms')
```

From above xpath none of them is working.

Comment: Your first XPath works against HTML snippet posted i.e it returns the `<span>` element successfully, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you need to match the `span` by its text content after spaces are normalized (using `normalized-space()`), then the XPath can be one of the following :

```
//span[normalized-space(text())='Click here to view terms']
//span[text()[normalized-space(.)='Click here to view terms']]
```

The first XPath only works if the target text node is the *first child node* of the `span`, while the second XPath should work regardless.

Comment: Thanks , Let me try.

Comment: @HelpingHands how about this one, did the XPath work?